# Apache VirtualHost Multiple Wildcard Domains / SSL

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, apache-2.4, wildcard-subdomain

I'm trying to figure out the configuration for the following:

Multiple Domains - (example1.com, example2.com, example3.com)
Single Virtual Host
Wildcard Subdomains (*.example1.com, *example2.com, etc)

My current configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAlias *.|DOMAIN|
     RewriteEngine on
     ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
     RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerAlias *.|DOMAIN|
     SSLEngine On
     DocumentRoot /SITES/WWW/public
     SSLCertificateFile /SITES/SSL/example1.com.crt
     SSLCertificateKeyFile /SITES/SSL/example1.com.key
     SSLCertificateChainFile /SITES/SSL/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

My VirtualHosts and redirects are working fine for all domains.  The issue I'm having is with SSL.  Each domain has its own SSL certificate and I can't seem to use the `|DOMAIN|` variable in the SSL configuration.

How do I go about configuring the SSL certificate based on the domain being used?

Thank you in advance for any guidance - really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try install vhost with this utility https://github.com/syntaxweaver/Ubuntu-ServConf
then you can duplicate vhost directory to other domain.
It will save your time to setup web server.